# DO NOT complete file-name with company

Tags: org-mode, company-mode, auto-complete-mode

I do not want emacs company mode to complete the file names in my org-mode buffer, as it wrongly replaces many words eg But becomes Butale (file-name, surname of person) and the becomes (themaskar, another surname). 
kindly help

Answer (score 1):

What company backends do you use? Remove `company-files` from `company-backends`.

> `company-files` is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `company-files.el`.
>
> `company-mode` completion backend existing file names.
>
> Completions works for proper absolute and relative files paths.
>   File paths with spaces are only supported inside strings.